# How can i save/insert data into table taking value from form?

Tags: python, django, forms, model

I had to do something like this:

```
def createpost(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PostForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            titlee = form.cleaned_data['title']
            contentt = form.cleaned_data['content']
            post = Post(title=titlee,content=contentt,created='2012-01-06',modified='2012-01-06') 
            post.save()
            return render_to_response('createpost.html', {"form": form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Is there any way to get form value like this `post = Post(form) ; post.save()` I don't want to get value individually like this: `titlee = form.cleaned_data['title']`

Any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

have a look at [model forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use model forms. To read about it, go here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/

After you create a ModelForm, your function should look similar to this:

```
def createpost(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PostForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/redirectsomewhereelse/')

    else:
        form = PostForm()
        return render_to_response('createpost.html', {"form": form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just call form.save() method if all data are valid.

Comment: Are you telling about ModelForm?

Comment: Yes, i do. If that's not the way you want to go, I'm afraid you will have to pick every single value "yourself".